# php mysql insert date of birth

Tags: php, mysql

I would like some help here.
I'm having a registration form with fields like name, surname, dob (date of birth), email etc.
When I'm trying to insert into my database everything works fine but for the dob.

The dob I get it from 3 select-option menus like $_POST['year'], $_POST['month'], $_POST['day'], but i haven't find out yet how to put those 3 values in one (dob) in order to insert it in my database correct and not taking the value 0000-00-00.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what is the datatype of your datetime field in db?

Comment: could you show us the database info (which kind of value is the dob column)?

Comment: why not store each value in its own column?  year / month / day ?  this way you can easily do a select on all users that were born in a specified year / month / day combination ...

Answer (score 2):

> The dob I get it from 3 select-option menus like $_POST['year'], $_POST['month'], $_POST['day']

Just validate and concatenate:

```
$yr=(integer)$_POST['year'];
$mo=(integer)$_POST['month'];
$da=(integer)$_POST['day'];
if (($yr>1910 && $yr<(integer)date('Y')) 
    && ($mo>0 && $mo<13)
    && ($da>0 && $da<32)) {
      $mysqldate=sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d", $yr, $mo, $da);
} else {
    trigger_error('date is not valid');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on rootatwc's reply, one crucial factor when inserting into the database is that DATETIME values must be quoted just like strings.

```
$name = "Sepp";
$surname = "Blatter";
$dob=$_POST['year'] . '-' . $_POST['month'] . '-' . $_POST['day'];

"insert into birthdays (name, surname, dob) values ('$name', '$surname', '$dob')"
```

You will also find mysql is quite forgiving, for example June can be expressed as -06- or -6-

As for extracting all entries for a certain year, that is laughably easy  - no need to put them into separate fields in your database:

```
select name from birthdays where YEAR(dob) = '1950';
```

**EDIT**

re-reading the question, it is not obvious that the OP is actually using a DATE field, hey, OP, use a DATE field - then you can browse your database and understand what dates are without having to try and decipher a 10 digit number... and you can use all the wonderful date functionality that Mysql comes with ...

Answer (score 0):

How do you want them stored in your database? Do you want them as a UNIX Timestamp, or as some other format?

Without you knowing how you want them formatted, we can't help.

Either way, you should use `mktime()` to convert to UNIX Timestamp, and then `date()` when you know how you want it formatted.

Comment: That won't work for people who were born before January 1, 1970

Comment: It will become a negative UNIX timestamp! :)

Comment: @Pekka: If you're using a signed datatype, it will work, but it's not a good idea anyway because of Y2K38 (UNIX timestamps only work 1901-2038, as that's the possible range of seconds since 1970-01-01 in a signed 32-bit int). It will break in interesting ways, should you need anything before 1901 or after 2038 (I've been bitten both ways).

Answer (score 0):

If your Apache is on a Linux server, you can use timestamp. Why only on a Linux server? Because Linux understands negative timestamps and that you will probably need them if you have people born before 1.1.1970.

```
$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day,$year);
```

Save the timestamp as an int.

```
echo date('d.m.Y',$timestamp);
```

to echo it.

Comment: he doesnt want to echo it and this is a wrong format for the database

Comment: @rootatwc He will want to print it someday... As for the format, since when "integer" is a wrong format for a database?

Comment: i am pretty sure his database field is set as DATE and not INT

Comment: @rootatwc Ok, but it can be changed too. Of course if the database is already containing dozens of entries, it's a bit difficult. But if he's just starting with an empty db, he can still change the field type. Nonetheless, I understand your comment and accept it, you are right.

Comment: How exactly are the native DATE types less broken than unixtime? Hint: you probably don't want to store something which will expire in 30 years into a unixtime column, it won't fit. Also, if you need to keep track of people born before 1901, you're in trouble the other way.

Comment: @Oltarus, no problems:) if you want you could change your answer accordingly,so i remove the downvote

Answer (score 0):

```
$timestamp=mktime(0,0,0,$_POST['month'],$_POST['day'],$_POST['year']);
$dob=date('Y-m-d',$timestamp);
```

The $dob value is ready to be inserted to your database

Or alternatively you could do:

```
$dob=$_POST['year'] . '-' . $_POST['month'] . '-' . $_POST['day'];
```

but you should escape the values first before inserting them to db, or use PDO

Answer (score 0):

change DOB field to `<input type="date" name="dob" class="datetime" />` html 5 would generate a datetimepicker for you. And then you can get it `$_POST['dob']`
And the dob field in database should be `TIMESTAMP`, `DATETIME` or `DATE` format, for universal date format.